# Access user's properties (with pivot table) laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a users table. The user has possibility to upload a post. The post is saved well to the database. The users can follow each other - so on a pivot table each follower_id has followees_id.

I need to get the posts of the current user followee's . I am kinda messed with getting it from a pivot table.

Here's my code so far:

controller:

```
protected function get_followee_posts($followee_posts) ////$followee_posts passed from the route.
{
  $user = $this->user;
  $user->followee()->attach($followee_posts);
  $followee_posts = User::find($followee_posts);


}
```

view:

```
<div class="following_posts">

<p> Posts from people you're following: <p>


@foreach ($user->follower_id->followee_id->posts as $post)
<form action="/html/tags/html_form_tag_action.cfm" method="post">
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" style="width:96%;height:90px;background-color:white;color:black;border:none;padding:2%;font:22px/30px sans-serif;">
{!! $posts->full_post !!} </textarea>

</form>
@endforeach
```

route:

```
Route::get('hub/{followee_posts}','HubController@get_followee_posts')->name('followee_posts');
```

I am getting an error with the current code saying:

```
ErrorException in 7340f90cc5faf1a298fcc646b7248b22 line 105:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Any help would be lovely. Thank you.

Comment: I think your using `attach()` incorrectly if your intention is simply to retrieve records from the database. `attach()` is used to insert a record in the intermediate table of a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Your not too specific about your schema, but this is how I would go about it.

## User Model

```
class User extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }


    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Follower');
    }  
}
```

## Follower Model

```
class Follower extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'followers';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }  

    public function posts() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
    }
}
```

## Post Model

```
class Post extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }  
}
```

The `followers` table would look something like this:

```
user_id
follower_id
```

You could then use eloquent method chains to get the posts of a users followers:

```
// Get Users object with followers and followers posts
// We use with() to eager load relationships
$user = User::with('followers.posts')->find(2);

// Return associative array of post objects
$postsArray = $user->followers->lists('posts');

// Combine posts into a single collection
$posts = (new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($postsArray))->collapse()->toArray();

print_r($posts);
```

Comment: I will let you know what's up with that. I do have all models above set and forgot to mention. Sorry. (I am off to sleep now)

Comment: @osherdo, edited the answer slightly, and tested it on a fresh install. Should do the job.

Comment: @ Jeemusu I have both followers and followees on the same table ('users').So it's all should be within the User.php Should I merge the Follower model to the User.php model?

Comment: @osherdo So each user can only have one followee? Or do you mean, followers and followee are both users?

Comment: In my example, the followers table has a user_id (followee) and a follower_id (follower) and both are users from the user table. So one user (followee) can have many followers.

Comment: Yes exactly. Followers and followees are both users (from 'users'table)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105277/discussion-between-osherdo-and-jeemusu).